# Get file path over ssh

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, directory, locate

I am developing an API in which I need the paths of multiple files from a remote server. The number of files varies from 100 - 500. The files are in different folders.

So, I am looping over and over again, like 10-50(depending on number of files) times, and then getting paths using ssh in my python api.

But I want an optimized solution for this problem. Right now, I am making ssh connection as many times as loop goes, which is slow, and also not the best thing to do.

I was thinking of copying the `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` of remote server daily in my local machine and then find the path using `locate` command using this db, If that is possible. OR Like storing the remote directory index in my local machine which I can query more fastly.

What are other better ways to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest looking at `tree` in general. There is also [this perl script over at UNIX SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144779/271588) that gets a whole directory tree in a parse-able file. Maybe that is a good starting point

Comment: `tree -if /your/path/here` seems a good way to achieve this

Comment: Jut type `locate --help` and read about the `-d` option. :-)

Comment: `locate` might not be a good solution, since typically it is outdated since it is run via cron-job once a day

Comment: Are NFS or samba available options?  They are meant for remote file access which is what you are doing.

Comment: where you able to solve this problem ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl mate I read your solution, thanks for that. I did not give it  a try yet, I am busy in some other work. I will give it a try in a week. Then I will upvote/accept your solution accordingly, and will tell you the difficulties faced.

Answer (score 3):

## tree

It seems `tree` is very fast at producing a list of all file paths. With SSH, and in the context of your script, a command could look like this

```
ssh user@host "tree -if --noreport /your/base/directory" > /tmp/tree.output
```

**-i** to have this *batch-like* output instead of the neat graphical tree
**-f** to print the full path prefix for each line
**--noreport** to cut off the *last two lines* since `tree` appends an empty line and a summary of files/directories found

The output would look like this

```
/var
/var/backups
/var/backups/alternatives.tar.0
/var/backups/alternatives.tar.1.gz
/var/backups/apt.extended_states.0
/var/backups/apt.extended_states.1.gz
/var/backups/apt.extended_states.2.gz
/var/backups/aptitude.pkgstates.0
/var/backups/dpkg.arch.0
/var/backups/dpkg.arch.1.gz
```

You might want to have a look at [the manpage here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), to see some options on how symbolic links are displayed with `-l`, etc

---

## find

`find` could also be used for the same purpose

```
ssh user@host "find /your/base/directory" > /tmp/find.output
```

again, you might want to check how you deal with symbolic links i[n the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).
With `find` you can also granulate in regards to types of files, patterns, depth etc...

---

Comment: Is `tree` better than `find` for this purpose?

Comment: @wjandrea, `tree` seems faster, but `find` is certainly also an option - I will update my answer

Comment: One important advantage of `find` over `tree` (which is a great tool though, no doubt) is that `find` should be preinstalled pretty much on every system, whereas `tree` usually needs to be installed first, which often restricts its usage to machines where one has admin rights.

Comment: @bytecommander, true...true.. but I guess since `locate` is an option, installing software is not an issue for OP